# How do i write the users input in a file in python?

Tags: python

```py
f = open("calculator.txt", "a+")

a = True

while a == True:

    operation = input("Please input an operation (+, -, *, /): ")
    num1 = float(input("Please input number 1: "))
    num2 = float(input("Please input number 2: "))
    if operation == "+":
       result = num1 + num2
    elif operation == "-":
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif operation == "*":
        print(num1 * num2)
    elif operation == "/":
        print(num1 / num2)
    answer = input("Run again? (Yes/No): ")
    if answer == "Yes":
        continue
    else:
        print("Goodbye ")
    exit()
```

How do i go about writing the results of the calculations in a file? Say the user inputs `5 + 5` and the program returns `10`, how would I save "10" in a text file? If possible the entire equation "5+5 = 10"

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  We expect you to use the available materials before posting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.format` to format result string and then use `print()` with `file=` parameter to write to file. For example:

```
with open('operations.txt', 'a') as f_out:
    while True:
        operation = input("Please input an operation (+, -, *, /): ")
        num1 = float(input("Please input number 1: "))
        num2 = float(input("Please input number 2: "))
        if operation == "+":
            result = num1 + num2
        elif operation == "-":
            result = num1 - num2
        elif operation == "*":
            result = num1 * num2
        elif operation == "/":
            result = num1 / num2

        result_string = '{} {} {} = {}'.format(num1, operation, num2, result)

        # print result string to screen:
        print(result_string)

        # save result string to file
        print(result_string, file=f_out)

        answer = input("Run again? (Yes/No): ")
        if answer == "Yes":
            continue
        else:
            print("Goodbye ")
            break
```

Prints:

```
Please input an operation (+, -, *, /): +
Please input number 1: 1
Please input number 2: 2
1.0 + 2.0 = 3.0
Run again? (Yes/No): Yes
Please input an operation (+, -, *, /): /
Please input number 1: 2
Please input number 2: 4
2.0 / 4.0 = 0.5
Run again? (Yes/No): no
Goodbye
```

And saves `operations.txt`:

```
1.0 + 2.0 = 3.0
2.0 / 4.0 = 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```py
    f.write(f'{num1} {operation} {num2} = {result}') # for example, '5 + 5 = 10'
    if answer == "Yes":
        continue
    else:
        print("Goodbye ")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change your program like this:

```
f = open("calculator.txt", "a+")

a = True

while a:
    operation = input("Please input an operation (+, -, *, /): ")
    num1 = float(input("Please input number 1: "))
    num2 = float(input("Please input number 2: "))
    if operation == "+":
       result = num1 + num2
    elif operation == "-":
       result = num1 - num2
    elif operation == "*":
       result = num1 * num2
    elif operation == "/":
        result = num1 / num2
    
    print(result)
    
    f.write(f"{num1}{operation}{num2} = {result}\n") #this will save the whole equation
    answer = input("Run again? (Yes/No): ")

    if answer == "Yes":
        continue
    else:
        print("Goodbye ")
        a = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
with open("calculator.txt", "a+") as myfile:
  myfile.write("\n" + result)
```

Inside if block

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file and write into it like this:

```
f = open("calculator.txt", "a+")
f.write(f"{num1} {operation} {num2} = {result}")
```